# Getting cors error when I deploy my backend on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I'm creating a mini server o Node JS I already push it on heroku. It is a very simple app. Just form where you can type your name, and email, after you submit the form the data will post into the database and also through nodemailer this data will be send to an email. I'm new to nodeJS so this is only my practice. Everything works fine when I'm on localhost. But when I publish my server to heroku and my front to my hosting I get this error in console:
[image]

and also this error in networktab:
[image]

I do some research about CORS Policy. So in my server I add cors dependencies and use it like this.

[image]

Here is my code for server:

```html
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mySql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

//Email
app.post("/send_email", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let customer = req.body;
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
    secure: true,
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  try {
    await transport.sendMail({
      from: `${customer.email}`,
      to: "test@test.sk",
      subject: "Testovací email",
      html: `<h1>Objednávka</h1>
              <p>Od: ${customer.firstName} ${customer.lastName}</p>
              <p>Email: ${customer.email}</p>
      `,
    });
    console.log("Email bol úspešne odoslaný");
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Odoslanie emailu nebolo úspešné: ", error);
  }
});

//database config
const db = mySql.createConnection({
  user: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error("error: " + err.message);
  }

  console.log("Pripojené k databáze");
});

app.post("/addCustomer", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const email = req.body.email;

  try {
    await db.query(
      "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (?,?,?)",
      [firstName, lastName, email],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.send("Values inserted");
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

My code for frontend:

```html
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const handleInputs = (e) => {
    setCustomer({
      ...customer,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSent = () => {
    axios.post("https://simple-form-my-first-node-app.herokuapp.com/send_email", customer);
  };

  const addCustomer = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSent();
    axios.post("https://simple-form-my-first-node-app.herokuapp.com/addCustomer", customer).then(() => {
      console.log("úspešne!");
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form className="my-5 mx-5">
      <Form.Group as={Row}>
        <Form.Label column sm={2} className="mb-3">
          Meno
        </Form.Label>
        <Col sm={6}>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Zadaj krstné meno"
            name="firstName"
            value={customer.firstName}
            onChange={handleInputs}
          />
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group as={Row}>
        <Form.Label column sm={2} className="mb-3">
          Priezvisko
        </Form.Label>
        <Col sm={6}>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Zadaj priezvisko"
            name="lastName"
            value={customer.lastName}
            onChange={handleInputs}
          />
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group as={Row}>
        <Form.Label column sm={2} className="mb-3">
          Email
        </Form.Label>
        <Col sm={6}>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            placeholder="Zadaj email"
            name="email"
            value={customer.email}
            onChange={handleInputs}
          />
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3">
        <Col sm={{ span: 10, offset: 2 }}>
          <Button type="submit" onClick={addCustomer}>
            Odoslať
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: The 30s duration is fishy. Are you sure you configured your URLs correctly?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I checked this.

Comment: I tried to check this via postman. And when I test this. I Got status 503 Service Unavailable. I don't understand this.

Comment: I tried sending a request to your server and while `/` worked (it returned `Cannot GET /` as expected) it timed out when trying to send to `addCustomer`. According to your code, you never return a response if an error occured, you just call `console.log` - this is a problem because the request will then never complete. I think you have an error (maybe invalid database connection details or something) and you don't see it - check the server log! (Also fix the code to return an error response in that case instead of hanging the request.)

Comment: Also you are mixing promises (async/await) and callbacks in a very weird way, I'd recommend cleaning up your code to use only of them (ideally async/await). Note though that Express (unlike Koa) won't handle rejected promises, so you also need a try/catch which returns an error response.

Comment: thank you for your comment. You're right I dont return a response. I fixed this. And now I have duration only some miliseconds instead of 30s. But still It doesn't work. Probably I have some issue with my database which is on my hosting. I contact my hosting provider if there can by some problem when I try to reach database.  I also try to check server logs. But i'm not sure if I do this correctly. In my terminal I type heroku logs --tail and very long report came out.

Comment: Now you probably have some syntax error or other reason why your app didn't even start, because even `/` produces the 503... you said "a long report came out" but did you check the error at the end of it?^^

Comment: I finally made it. I looked at the logs. There was connection error to my db.  I realized that I didn't set my .env file on heroku. So I made it through heroku config:set command. I copied there my variables from my .env file.

Now its working. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. You could create an answer to your own question below and accept it, to mark this as solved and to provide a reference what the solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works. First mistake I had was that I didn't realized that my .env file is not included when I publish my app to heroku. So I do this with `heroku config:set` command. I would like to mention here that be carefull when you type your passwords here because it doesn't take ^ symbol.

Second thing was that I didn't had in my package.json file in scripts section `start: node index.js` so when I push my app to heroku the app didn't even start.

Answer (score 0):

if your using

```
app.use(cors());
```

as middleware you dont need to call it again in your endpoints

```
app.post("/send_email", async (req, res, next())
```

your essentially sending your response headers twice i believe